# Trouble Shooting errdisabled Cause

Tags: cisco, configuration, cisco-catalyst

I have a Cisco Catalyst 3850. I added a network module with 4 gbic for fiber connection. The module is not showing any lights on either side of the connection. After the searching the depths of the internet I found out that when adding a network module like I did I have to enable the media-type of sfp for those interfaces. This is what I have tried.

```
enable

conf t

int tengigabitethernet 1/1/1

media-type sfp
```

it's not wanting to take this command.
is this the right way to enable media-type sfp?

Show inventory command:

```
flcoffice_48m_01#show inv
NAME: "c3xxx Stack", DESCR: "c3xxx Stack"
PID: WS-C3850-48T      , VID: V04  , SN: FCW1905C178

NAME: "Switch 1", DESCR: "WS-C3850-48T"
PID: WS-C3850-48T      , VID: V04  , SN: FCW1905C178

NAME: "Switch 1 - Power Supply A", DESCR: "Switch 1 - Power Supply A"
PID: PWR-C1-350WAC     , VID: V01  , SN: LIT19221FY 

NAME: "Switch 1 FRU Uplink Module 0", DESCR: "4x10G Uplink Module"
PID: C3850-NM-4-10G    , VID: V01  , SN: FOC19238XKL

NAME: "TenGigabitEthernet1/1/1", DESCR: "1000BaseSX SFP"
PID: GLC-SX-MMD         , VID: V01  , SN: FNS19270TD6    

NAME: "TenGigabitEthernet1/1/2", DESCR: "1000BaseSX SFP"
PID: GLC-SX-MMD         , VID: V01  , SN: FNS19270TQ0    

NAME: "TenGigabitEthernet1/1/3", DESCR: "1000BaseSX SFP"
PID: GLC-SX-MMD         , VID: V01  , SN: FNS1920059J
```

here is the errdisable recovery command:

```
flcoffice_48m_01#show errdisable recovery 
ErrDisable Reason            Timer Status
-----------------            --------------
arp-inspection               Disabled
bpduguard                    Disabled
channel-misconfig (STP)      Disabled
dhcp-rate-limit              Disabled
dtp-flap                     Disabled
gbic-invalid                 Disabled
inline-power                 Disabled
l2ptguard                    Disabled
link-flap                    Disabled
mac-limit                    Disabled
loopback                     Disabled
pagp-flap                    Disabled
port-mode-failure            Disabled
pppoe-ia-rate-limit          Disabled
psecure-violation            Disabled
security-violation           Disabled
sfp-config-mismatch          Disabled
storm-control                Disabled
udld                         Disabled
vmps                         Disabled
psp                          Disabled
Recovery command: "clear     Disabled
```

Comment: What error message do you get when you issue the `media-type sfp` command? Can you post the output of `show inventory`? (Please add the `show inventory` output by editing your question)

Comment: You don't need that command unless there is a corresponding copper port that shares the port. It just clarifies whether you use the built-in copper port or the SFP port. The module for the 3850 only has SFP ports, so you don't use this command.

Comment: I agree with Ron. We have several little brothers (the 3650 line) to your switches, modules, and SFPs here that I've integrated and configured from scratch (I just did one yesterday) and we haven't needed to use the `media-type` command. When a connection doesn't light up for us, we look at the fiber, make sure it's the right kind, plugged in correctly, etc.

Comment: Also, on the show int command the tengigabitethernet are showing errdisabled. @ToddWilcox

Comment: Errdisabled means there's a reason why the system has disabled the port. This question should probably be edited to one about troubleshooting errdisabled ports. Run `show errdisable recovery` to see the reason why the port was disabled. Then you can troubleshoot that reason. See here: http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/lan-switching/spanning-tree-protocol/69980-errdisable-recovery.html

Comment: You have something configured incorrectly for how you want to use the ports if you are getting `errdisable` on the port. You should edit the question to include the switch configuration. Don't type it in, but copy and paste into the question. These sorts of questions should be asked on [Network Engineering](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @RonMaupin Probably best to flag for migration if you think it should be moved rather than risk leading a new user to cross-post. I don't know what the meta is on the Server Fault side on purely networking questions but if I recall correctly I seem to remember reading it's fine either here or at NE.SE.

Comment: I think you should issue `errdisable recovery cause all` in config mode and then `errdisable recovery interval 60` (replace the last number with a time, in seconds, you would like ports to stay disabled before trying again). After that, ctrl-z (or exit) and run `show errdisable recovery` again and it should show the reason(s) for errdisables at the bottom of the output.

Comment: @ToddWilcox, the moderators on Network Engineering follow the SE guidelines, and they will not migrate, or accept for migration, any question which doesn't have an answer worth saving.

Comment: @RonMaupin I always forget that.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your interfaces are in err-disabled. If so, it's due to a known Cisco bug where it states gbic-invalid (even though it is valid) , you can manually shut no shut the interface with the SFP or add errdisable recovery cause gbic-invalid to your config. Possibly the bug will be fixed in future IOS releases.

Tidy