# Cisco catalyst network module 3850-nm-4-10g link is off

Tags: cisco, configuration

I am going through the installation guide for the cicso module referenced above and It says if  the leds are not on that "link is off". It doesn't say what this means or what causes this. Is it just a bad connection? or cause by a configuration or something else?

Comment: If you did a `no shutdown` on the interfaces on both sides, there are lots of other reasons. You should be asking this question on [Network Engineering](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/). You need to make sure the SFPs are the same on both sides of the link, that they are compatible with the fiber type, that the fiber type is appropriate for 10 Gbps at the cable length you are using, etc.

Comment: Is this the same issue as in your other question? It seems like it. If you don't want to move this to Network Engineering then your original question is here: http://serverfault.com/questions/761382/trouble-shooting-errdisabled-cause